# Java - Is the JDK part of the core java language?

Tags: java

I'm doing an aprenticeship in an IT company as a developer.

When I ask my colleagues if the `List<>` item is part of the java core language, they say yes. But for me it looks like an extra feature, which is heavily used, but nonetheless an external resource. For me it's kind of confusing, because I can use the `List<>` in a for-each loop like:

`for(Object o : objectList){}`

So the `List<>` has to interact somewhere with the native `for` loop, so that it works.

My Questions:

*The `List<>` is part of the JDK, and the JDK is external, like the Standard-C-Library for C, right?

*So the Java compiler doesn't know what a `List<>` is and also just reads it from the JDK, like any other framework, right?

*If my assertions are right, somewhere in the `List.java`(or however it's called) file has to be an expression, that tells the compiler how to use it in a for-each loop?

Comment: Are you looking to find out [How does the Java 'for each' loop work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85190/335858)?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was a bit more eager already.

Comment: The compiler (`javac`) doesn't know what `List` is. It has to look into `rt.jar` (for "runtime") to find the class. So no, the development kit isn't part of the core language.

Comment: TL;DR: `List` is not part of the Java Language. And as the answer linked by  @dasblinkenlight explained, not only `List`s can be interated by an `foreach`-loop, but any datastructure, implementing the `Iterable` interface, including self-written datastructures.